# Is column order important in mysql?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I read somewhere that column order in mysql is important. I believe they were referring to the indexed columns.

**QUESTION:** If column order is important, when and why is it important?

The reason I ask is because I have a table in mysql similar to the one below.
The primary index is on the left and I have an index on the far right. Is this bad?
It is a MyISAM table and will be used predominantly for selects (no inserts, deletes or updates).

```
-----------------------------------------------
|  Primary index | data1|  data2  | d3| Index |
-----------------------------------------------
|      1         |   A  |   cat   | 1 |   A   | 
|      2         |   B  |  toads  | 3 |   A   |
|      3         |   A  |  yabby  | 7 |   B   |
|      4         |   B  | rabbits | 1 |   B   |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I can't imagine that the order matters. It might matter at a low level, but surely a DBMS can optimize this so you will never have to worry about something like this. I'd like to see an authoritative answer on this though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Column order is only important when defining indexes, as this affects whether an index is suitable to use in executing a query. (This is true of all RBDMS's, not just MySQL)

e.g.

Index defined on columns `MyIndex(a, b, c)` in that order.

A query such as

```
select a from mytable
where c = somevalue
```

probably won't use that index to execute the query (depends on several factors such as row count, column selectivity etc)

Whereas, it will most likely choose to use an index defined as `MyIndex2(c,a,b)`

Update: see [use-the-index-luke.com](http://use-the-index-luke.com/) (thanks Greg).

Comment: This is correct, read http://use-the-index-luke.com/ for some relevant info on it.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, the order of the columns is important when an index is applied to multiple columns (composite index). In my example above where the index is on just one column, it shouldn't be a problem. Does this sound right?